# How do I verify that data is synchronized to new DC?

Tags: cassandra

I am adding a new data center into my Cassandra cluster using `nodetool rebuild`. How to check if data/keyspaces are synchronized in my new data center so that I can redirect traffic to this data center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick way to verify that the replicas are in sync other than by running a rolling repair (one node at a time). For example:

```
$ nodetool repair -pr
```

If there is nothing to repair, it will be a no-op.

Note that the reason for running a repair one node at a time is so it won't overload your cluster. Cheers!